# Matplotlib ticks in the wrong location on additional axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, customization

I would like to have an upper X axis with ticks at identical positions (on the axis) as the original x axis ticks (the tick labels can be different though). It seems easy enough to do, but I am not sure why the code below doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

X = np.linspace(11,80,1000)
Y = 2*np.sin(X)*np.exp(-X/20.)

ax1.plot(X,Y)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

old_ticks = ax1.get_xticks()
ax2.set_xticks(old_ticks)

plt.show()
```

The output is shown below: clearly, the ticks on the top axis are not in the same location on the axis as the ticks below (namely, on the top axis there are 7 ticks versus only 6 ticks on the bottom).

Why is this so?

[image: Offset ticks on the second x axis]

EDIT: Setting xlim (as suggested below) works only on initial plot, but not when one zooms in on different regions. I added a callback function to, upon zooming in/out, add the ticks on `ax2` in the same location as they are on `ax1`, but this doesn't seem to work.

Also, the reason I'm using `twiny` is because eventually the shown tick values for `ax2` will depend on the `ax1` tick values in a non-linear way. I just want the ticks to be in the same position on the axis.
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

X = np.linspace(11,80,1000)
Y = 2*np.sin(X)*np.exp(-X/20.)

ax1.plot(X,Y)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax2.set_xticks(ax1.get_xticks())

def on_xlim_changed(ax1):
    ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
    ax2.set_xticks(ax1.get_xticks())

ax1.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed',on_xlim_changed)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Good question, suffice it to say that six years have passed and there's still no trivial answer to this on the net. In your second example code, if you swap these two lines you'll get a nice initial figure but indeed the zooming will cause the ticks to become misaligned: `ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim()) ax2.set_xticks(ax1.get_xticks())`
Some potentially helpful posts (also in my bounty description): stackoverflow.com/a/35904761/2542091 stackoverflow.com/a/27344398/2542091

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
```

also, if you just need ticks to be shown on the top, you do not need a `twiny` axis, and you may simply do

```
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
```

Comment: this seems to work only when the plot is initially shown, but not when one zooms into different regions on the plot. The reason I want to use `twiny` is because I want to have the ticks in the same position (as on the bottom axis), but the tick labels will be different. I edited my question above to include the "zoom-in" clarification

Comment: @behzad.nouri for some reason, the `set_ticks_postion('both')` doesn't work with matplotlib `'3.1.3'`. It's possible to set them on `top` or `bottom` (`left` and `right` for Y-axis), but not `both` or `none`.

Comment: @RonOGara `ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())` suggested above works for me, even in case of pan or zoom

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is to disable zooming on the secondary axis with `ax2.set_navigate(False)`. Adjusting the limits in the callback only has an effect if zooming does not affect the limits of the axis itself:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.linspace(11, 80, 1000)
y = 2 * np.sin(x) * np.exp(-x / 20.)

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_navigate(False)  # Important!

old_ticks = ax1.get_xticks()
ax2.set_xticks(old_ticks)
ax1.grid(linewidth=1, ls='--') # Added to be able to see the (mis-)alignment better.

ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())

def on_xlim_changed(ax_):
    ax2.set_xticks(ax_.get_xticks())
    ax2.set_xlim(ax_.get_xlim())

ax1.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', on_xlim_changed)

plt.show()
```

### Example of zooming without `set_navigate(False)`

[image: Zooming w/o <code>set_navigate(False)</code>]

### Zooming with the code as posted in the answer

[image: Zooming with the code as posted in the answer]

Comment: This simple, huh? ;) Fantastic! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Locator` functionality

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mticks

N = 5
ax1.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(mticks.LinearLocator(numticks=N))
ax2.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(mticks.LinearLocator(numticks=hN))
```

([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LinearLocator)) which will put `N` evenly spaced ticks on the axes.

The `Formatter`s will then take care of formatting the labels.

Beware that this can lean to very strange looking labels.  The reason the locations are jumping around is that `AutoLocator`, which is the default locator, tries to put the ticks at 'nice' locations (integers, even multiples etc) so you don't get tick labels that look like '1.52547841082'.